# php incremente a date of x days / concatenation / management of days off and weekend

Tags: php, javascript, date, increment, weekend

I'm trying to do a simply addition,
Just in order to display some dates so Acutaly

I've done something like that:

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)): 

   echo  $req="INSERT INTO `agenda` SET
     `code_s`= '".$row['code_s']."',
     `titre` ='".$row['titre']."',
     `action` ='".$row['action']."',
     `libelle`='".$row['libelle']."',
      `date_action`='".date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+"'.$row['jour'].'" days'))."',
      `qualite`='".$da['qualite']."',
      `n_doss`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['n_doss'])."',
      `code_client`='".$creance['code_client']."'<br>";
      endwhile;     };
```

Amm is in the following line that does not display any mistake:

```
 `date_action`='".date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+"'.$row['jour'].'" days'))."',
```

What I was trying is to display the date incremented of the number of days contained in the var $row['jour'], but Actualy it just display to me 1970-01-01, so I do not understand why, because all the var have a positive number in that var.

Moreover I have one javascript function:

Like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getdate2() {
        var items = new Array();
        var itemCount = document.getElementsByClassName("datepicker hasDatepicker");

        for (var i = 0; i < itemCount.length; i++) {
            items[i] = document.getElementById("date" + (i + 1)).value;
        }



        for (var i = 0; i < itemCount.length; i++) {
            items[i] = document.getElementById("date" + (i + 1)).value;
            var itemDtParts = items[i].split("-");
            var itemDt = new Date(itemDtParts[2], itemDtParts[1] - 1, itemDtParts[0]);
        <?php $sql="SELECT * FROM `societe` WHERE `id`=1"; $result=mysql_query($sql) or die; $data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);?><?php if($data['samedi']==0) {?>
            if (itemDt.getDay() == 6) {

                itemCount[i].value = (itemDt.getDate() < 9 ? "0" : "")+ (itemDt.getDate()+2)+ "-" + (itemDt.getMonth() < 9 ? "0" : "") + (itemDt.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + itemDt.getFullYear();


            }
            <?php } ?>
            if (itemDt.getDay() == 0) {

               itemCount[i].value = (itemDt.getDate() < 9 ? "0" : "")+ (itemDt.getDate()+1)+ "-" + (itemDt.getMonth() < 9 ? "0" : "") + (itemDt.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + itemDt.getFullYear();


            }

        }
       return items;
       }
</script>
```

Actualy this function only incremente dates if a day is a sunday or a satturday, it depens of which is the parameter setting from the database on this line:

```
<?php $sql="SELECT * FROM `societe` WHERE `id`=1"; $result=mysql_query($sql) or die; $data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);?><?php if($data['samedi']==0) {?>
                if (itemDt.getDay() == 6) {

                    itemCount[i].value = (itemDt.getDate() < 9 ? "0" : "")+ (itemDt.getDate()+2)+ "-" + (itemDt.getMonth() < 9 ? "0" : "") + (itemDt.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + itemDt.getFullYear();


                } ?>
```

Because sometimes some companies does work on satturday.

I would like to know how to apply this function on the new date, before it is insert to the database?

Is there a way I can apply a javascript function to a none-object item in php?

Receive all my utmost Respect.

Kind regards.

SP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for the php part of the question:

```
`date_action` = '". date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date("Y-m-d"). "+".$row['jour']."days"))."'
```

**Edit:**

```
 `date_action` = '". date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date("Y-m-d"). "+".$row['jour']."days"))."'
```

Comment: ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING i

Comment: ok Thanks for this answer, it works fine for that. Do you have any idea on how can I apply the javascript function ? kind regards. SP

Comment: np, trying to understand your js question :)...what do u mean by `none-object in php` ?

Comment: ok, let me guess, you want to insert `itemCount[i].value` or `items` into the DB?

Comment: yes Sir that is right none object is actually none in the input

Comment: you would need to use ajax, here's the manual http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ here's an example http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax